# Using IDocumentEvents_Event from a .NET 4 assembly within ArcMap

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, .net

Are there a known issues when working with events from .NET 4 COM assemblies within ArcMap?

For example, when using IDocumentEvents_Event from a .NET 4 assembly in ArcObjects, the event appears to work properly, but disables the standard right-click context menu behavior in ArcMap.  Changing nothing in the assembly except the target to .NET 3.5 or .NET 2.0 will "restore" the default behavior.  Is this a COM issue, or an ArcObjects issue?  If the latter, is there a potential workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vote for .Net 4.0 support idea here: http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008Dwn